# Occurrence of a string in all the file names within a folder

Tags: c#, string, file

I want to find how many file names, within a folder, contains a particular string. I have no idea how I should do it with C#.

For example, in folder D:\A, there are

```
fileApple_1.bmp
fileApple_2.bmp
fileApple_3.bmp
fileApple_4.bmp
fileApple_5.bmp
fileOrange_1.bmp
fileOrange_2.bmp
fileOrange_3.bmp
fileOrange_4.bmp
fileOrange_5.bmp
fileGrape_1.bmp
fileGrape_2.bmp
fileGrape_3.bmp
```

and I want to find out how many files with their name containing "Grape", and we know the answer should be 3, because

```
fileGrape_1.bmp
fileGrape_2.bmp
fileGrape_3.bmp
```

are the files that have "Grape" in their name.

Thanks!

Comment: To the downvoter: Can you please tell me why this thread gets downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string searchTerm = "grape";
int grapeCount = 
    new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath)
        .EnumerateFiles(string.Format("*{0}*", searchTerm))
        .Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string keyword = "Grape";
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("D:\\", "*" + keyword + "*");
```

Then you can retrieve the Length property of files array to find number of occurences